# API Jmeter request modification upon using JSR223 PreProcessor

Tags: api, rest, jmeter, jmx, assertion

Hello could someone help me how to remove the additional "{ and "} on the request upon using JSR223 PreProcessor, This is the syntax I use to generate the request below. Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Screenshot:

[image]

Expected Result:

```
    "metrics": {

            "com.cixsoft.agent.metric.NetworkMetric": "NetworkMetric.json",
            "com.cixsoft.agent.metric.ProcessInfoMetric": "ProcessInfoMetric.json",
            "com.cixsoft.agent.metric.CpuMetric": "CpuMetric.json"
    },
```

Actual Result:

```
    "metrics": {
        "{ -<< Remove this open curly braces
            "com.cixsoft.agent.metric.NetworkMetric": "NetworkMetric.json",
            "com.cixsoft.agent.metric.ProcessInfoMetric": "ProcessInfoMetric.json",
            "com.cixsoft.agent.metric.CpuMetric": "CpuMetric.json"
      "} -<< -<< Remove this close curly braces
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Don't post code as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)
2. [Give us a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
3. Follow other recommendations from [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article

For example we need to know:

1. The value of the `agentSimUserMetric` variable
2. How exactly you're using this `userMetric` variable

Looking at my crystal ball I see that you have something like:

```
"metrics" : {
    ${userMetric}
}
```

while you need to have just

```
"metrics" : ${userMetric}
```

so I'm 99.9% sure that it's **you** who is adding these curly braces and asking us for a piece of advice regarding how to remove them sounds kind of weird.

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Actually this is my request:

{
"os": "B",
"kernel": "A",
"bootstrapServers": "K",
"timeOffset":"0",
"submanagerlogs":"false",
"metrics": {
"{
    "com.cixsoft.agent.metric.NetworkMetric": "NetworkMetric.json",
    "com.cixsoft.agent.metric.ProcessInfoMetric": "ProcessInfoMetric.json",
    "com.cixsoft.agent.metric.CpuMetric": "CpuMetric.json"
}"
},
"preDefinedAgents": {}
}


I just want to parameterize the metrics so I could playaround and make it flexible.